# Notepad++ Javascript format style and list of variables

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, formatting, notepad++

I'm using JSTool plugin for Notepad ++ but I have problem with formating list of variables. Visual Studio formats list in this way:

```
var test = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test3 = 3;
```

And N++ formats lists in this way:

```
var test = 1,
test2 = 2,
test3 = 3;
```

You see... N++ lost indentations before second and third line... It is very annoying. How can I change that? Is there any solution?

Comment: How this is relevant to my question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Notepad++, but on many editor if you do a Maj+Enter when you are at the end of a line the editor will make a new line with the indentation of the previous one.

Maybe on Notepad++ do this will produce the result you want :

```
var test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,*Maj+Enter*
    test2 = 3,*Maj+Enter*
```

Comment: Well...but I need to achieve this style for entire file using one command. Sometimes I work with legacy code and I have to reformat it :)

Comment: Maybe you this is article on Notepadd++ will help you : http://www.papervisions.com/how-to-re-indent-your-cc-code-using-notepad/